# how to use list express in scss?

Tags: css, sass

I try to convert a sass style into a scss style format.

the orgininal sass file is:

```
$family-sans-serif: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
```

I try to use:

```
$family-sans-serif: ("Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif);
```

But I get error fellowing:

```
 Error in beforeCreate hook: "Error: Module build failed: 
 $family-sans-serif: ("Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif);
 ^
 Media query expression must begin with '('
```

How to defined variable in scss? espically the variable is a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use these for variables in projects, Depending if your using @font-face etc

```
$font-josefin:  "JosefinSans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
$font-raleway:  "Raleway", sans-serif;
```

In my project I call the variables.

```
body {
    font-size: $default-px;
    font-size: $default-rem;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: $font-raleway;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to append a semicolon to the line, then you have valid SCSS. Eg.: `$family-sans-serif: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;`